# To where the sum $\sum_{n=2}^N \frac{a^n}{n!}$ converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, factorial

I'm trying to implement this expression in an algorithm, however computing factorial is very time-consuming, so I'm trying to find an equivalent equation that avoids that factorial term.

It can be an approximation too.

Thank you very much if you have any ideas

BR

Comment: Yes, I just want to get rid of that factorial term, maybe having an alternative expression

Comment: When computed incrementally, the factorial is not time-consuming. And this series converges very quickly, so time should not be an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be strict
$$\sum_{n=2}^m \frac{a^n}{n!}=e^a\frac{ \Gamma (m+1,a)}{\Gamma (m+1)}-a-1$$ Now, if you want an approximation of the "bad" term
$$\frac{\Gamma (m+1,a)}{\Gamma (m+1)}\approx 1-\frac{a^{m+1} e^{m (1-\log (m))-a}}{\sqrt{2 \pi }\, m^{3/2}}$$
Trying with $a=\pi$ and $m=10$, the "exact" value of the above is $0.99957$ while the approximation would give $0.99965$.

Using the approximation, then 
$$\sum_{n=2}^m \frac{a^n}{n!}\approx (e^a-a-1)-\frac{a^{m+1} e^{m (1-\log (m))}}{\sqrt{2 \pi }\, m^{3/2}}$$

**Edit**

If you want better, you could use
$$\frac{\Gamma (m+1,a)}{\Gamma (m+1)}\approx 1-\frac{a^{m+1} e^{m (1-\log (m))-a}}{\sqrt{2 \pi }\, m^{3/2}}\left(1+\frac{12 a-13}{12 m} \right)$$ which, for the este case, would give $0.9995740$ while the exact value is $0.9995723$. Big improvement for a very small correction.

Answer (score 2):

We have $\sum_{n=2}^N \frac{a^n}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^N \frac{a^n}{n!}-1-a$ and $\sum_{n=0}^N \frac{a^n}{n!} \to e^a$ as $N \to \infty.$

Thus

$$\sum_{n=2}^N \frac{a^n}{n!} \to e^a -1-a$$

as $N \to \infty.$

I hope , that it helps.

Comment: Do you know the expansion $e^x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}$ ?

Comment: @boaz: did you read the answer at all ??

Comment: Yes, I know this expansion. I wrote $ \sum_{n=0}^N \frac{a^n}{n!} \to e^a$ as $ N \to \infty.$ And this means nothing else than $e^a=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{a^n}{n!}.$

Comment: @MarinoMtz: "small $N$s" is contradictory with "converges to". Fix your question.

Answer (score 2):

```
s:= 0
p:= a² / 2
n:= 3
while s + p != s:
    s:= s + p
    p:= a . p / n
    n:= n + 1
```

(adjust the termination criterion if you want a finite number of terms).

Comment: Essentially, just use $(n+1)!=(n+1)\times n!$ and save the result.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: better compute `p` directly, you don't need the factorial value.